# How do I make urlpatterns and patterns avaliable for settings.py?

Tags: python, django

To access static, I need this code in setting.py

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

settings.DEBUG= True
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'media/(?P<path>.*)',
        'serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

however, `urlpatterns` is not available in setting.py. It returns `NameError: name 'urlpatterns' is not defined`. `urlpatterns` is in `urls.py`

```
"""THIS IS URLS.PY"""

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),url(r'^rango/', views.about, name='about'))
```

How do I make  `urlpatterns` avaliable for `setting.py`

The dirrectory:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you do the opposite? put all the urls in urls.py seems more logic. Add this to urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'media/(?P<path>.*)',
        'serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

Comment: This way the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you've understood something wrongly. That URLs code belongs in urls.py, not in settings.py. You import settings into urls, not the other way round.